# Visual studio zooming out shortcut issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Many places point out these shortcuts are for zooming in and out

*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>*

*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>*

I use VS 2015 and only zoom in is working with this shortcut. What could be the problem?

I'm using Windows10 and mostly US International keyboard(note that changing language did not help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same for me, although I don't use the shortcut (I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mousewheel instead). The issue is that there is no keyboard shortcut to the "View.ZoomOut" command bound. If you set it in the Keyboard options at Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard, it should work.